# Elasticsearch Autocomplete Issues

Tags: nest, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to create an Autocompletion using Elasticsearch.net, but i keep getting an Invalid response.

But cant figure out why?

My Request looks like this

```
var descriptor = new SearchDescriptor<EmployeeDocument>()
                .Index("employees").Type("employee").From(page - 1).Size(pageSize)
                .Suggest(
                s => s.Completion(
                    "my-completion-suggest",
                    c => c
                    .Field(f1 => f1.Description)
                    .Field(f1 => f1.empfirstname)
                    .Contexts(
                        queriesDescriptor => queriesDescriptor.Context(
                            "query-descriptor",
                            queryDescriptor => queryDescriptor.Prefix(true).Context(query)))));
            var response3 = await this.client.SearchAsync<EmployeeDocument>(descriptor);
```

the error i am getting is

```
Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST: /employees/employee/_search
 Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] BadResponse: Node: http://192.168.2.29:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.3543244
 ServerError: ServerError: 400Type: search_phase_execution_exception Reason: "all shards failed"
```

This is how i am calling the method

```
var results1 = await service.SearchAsync("brenda", page, pageSize);
var results8 = await service.SearchAsync("something else", page, pageSize);
```

My model is also very straightforward. I left out some properties

```
  [ElasticsearchType(Name = "employee")]
        public class EmployeeDocument
        {
            //[Text(Name = "pkempid")]
            public long pkempid { get; set; }

            //[Text(Name = "empfirstname")]
            public string empfirstname { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Description` and `empfirstname` need to be mapped as [`completion` field data types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-suggesters-completion.html). The `CompletionField` type in NEST can be used for the property type, which will be mapped as a `completion` data type through [automapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/auto-map.html).

Additionally, a completion suggester can only specify one field, so chaining multiple calls to `.Field()` will not work as expected (the last call will be the field used). You can however specify multiple suggesters in one request targeting different fields. It's more usual though, rather than having multiple completion fields in a mapping, to specify multiple *input* values to a single completion field.

The use case for the completion suggester is to provide fast "search as you type" autocompletion functionality, trading off the power of more complex analysis chains that can be performed with `text` field data types.

Comment: I dont want to map those fields as completion fields because then i have to pre-set those fields with suggestions. I ended up using NGrams, seems to do what i want

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "...i have to pre-set those fields with suggestions". The completion suggester field still undergoes analysis but is designed for _fast_ _prefix_ autocompletion, so if you have a need to suggest differently, you can change the analyzer or use `text` datatypes and a more complex analysis and search strategy.

Comment: What I mean by  "...i have to pre-set those fields with suggestions" is that I was under the impression that I have to set those fields, like in the link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-suggesters-completion.html  I have to set "suggest" : [ "Nevermind", "Nirvana" ]. What I want to do is search as you type and the values from ES will just be filtered by what I type. I cant find an example like that. But it might be ignorance from my side. The closest i could get to what i want is the NGram solution

Comment: ngrams and edgengrams are definitely one way to solve autocompletion, with tokenization taking place on the inputs to the fields on which you specify an analyzer that uses ngrams / edgengrams. With the completion field datatype, you can supply multiple inputs to the field, where each input will be analyzed. Completion suggester is less flexible but will almost certainly be faster than a custom analysis chain due to using a different data structure (FST) that is loaded into memory on demand. Which to use when totally depends, and you might end up using a combination of them :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured out how to do autocomplete, I ended up using `Edge NGram Tokenizer` First thing I needed to do was setup my indexes with the correct filters.

```
var response = this.client.CreateIndex(
                    ElasticConfig.IndexName,
                    index => index.Mappings(
                        ms => ms.Map<EmployeeDocument>(
                            m => m.Properties(
                                p => p
                                    .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.EmpFirstName).Analyzer("auto-complete").Fields(ff => ff.Keyword(k => k.Name("keyword"))))
                                    .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.pkEmpID).Analyzer("auto-complete-id").Fields(ff => ff.Keyword(k => k.Name("keyword"))))
                                    .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.Description).Analyzer("auto-complete").Fields(ff => ff.Keyword(k => k.Name("keyword")))))))
                        .Settings(f => f.Analysis(
                            analysis => analysis
                                .Analyzers(
                                    analyzers => analyzers
                                        .Custom("auto-complete", a => a.Tokenizer("standard").Filters("lowercase", "auto-complete-filter"))
                                        .Custom("auto-complete-id", a => a.Tokenizer("standard").Filters("lowercase", "auto-complete-id-filter")))
                                        .TokenFilters(tokenFilter => tokenFilter
                                                                    .EdgeNGram("auto-complete-filter", t => t.MinGram(3).MaxGram(5))
                                                                    .EdgeNGram("auto-complete-id-filter", t => t.MinGram(1).MaxGram(5))))));
```

Then for the actual search

```
var response = await this.client.SearchAsync<EmployeeDocument>(
                           x => x.Index("default-index").Type("employee").From(page - 1).Size(pageSize)
                                .Query(q => q
                                    .MultiMatch(m => m
                                        .Query(query)
                                        .Fields(f => f
                                                        .Field(_ => _.EmpFirstName)
                                                        .Field(_ => _.pkEmpID)
                                                        .Field(_ => _.Description))))
                                         .Highlight(
                                            h => h.PreTags("<mark>").PostTags("</mark>").Fields(
                                                f => f.Field(p => p.EmpFirstName),
                                                f => f.Field(p => p.pkEmpID),
                                                f => f.Field(p => p.Description))));
```